# Thickbox jQuery Issue: Works fine until after AJAX sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, thickbox

So I have an image gallery that uses thickbox.  When I first load the page and click an image, it loads fine into the thickbox.  However, after performing an ajax sort of the images and echoing back identical thickbox urls, clicking on one of the images displays the content in a new browser window rather than a thick box.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by `ajax` sort? Can you describe the process in a little more detail?

Comment: I have a dropdown box that just sends a jquery ajax request to the database and replaces the current images in the exact same format but with different back end sorting options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

Had to had `tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');` in my ajax callback

[Php returns thickbox link that doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249130/php-returns-thickbox-link-that-doesnt-work)